# hide the path of the php file in ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I dont know if this possible

But  I have an `ajax` function in my javascript and as all, we know we need to provide `php file path` in the ajax request and this will be visible to all the users and unfortunately they can see the path of the ajax files and where they are stored .but i dont want this to happen i dont want user or client to see my ajax filed Is there a way to hide this path from the client, from seeing the path of ajax files? i know its something obfuscation but i only want the path to be done is it possible?

**Update**

so is there any way to stop user from viewing or opening php files from the url, I mean if user enters the path of ajax files and hits enter he can see all my files over there and he can easily hack my data so is there a way to stop user from entering them , i want only my pages to access php files not from users url,Thanks

Comment: I am probably going to regret this but, Why?

Comment: The user can look at the HTTP requests (e.g. with the Chrome console, IE Web Developer whatsit or Firebug), so this is entirely pointless. If you want the browser to be able to make an HTTP request, you have to allow your users to know its location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible. The browser has to request the URI. The user can see what resources their browser is requesting.

"Ajax files" are not a special case. You need to secure them in exactly the same way as any other resource you provide over HTTP. i.e. use authentication and authorisation to make sure that only users who are allowed to access them do, input validation to make sure that any data sent to them is acceptable, and escaping to make sure that the data doesn't cause you problems if you try to insert it into SQL/HTML/JS/any other data format.

Response to update:

> so is there any way to stop user from viewing or opening php files from the url

Still No!

> I mean if user enters the path of ajax files and hits enter he can see all my files over there

You can configure your server to not serve a DirectoryIndex. The specifics depend on the server. Alternatively you can put a blank index.html file there.

> and he can easily hack my data

How?

> so is there a way to stop user from entering them

No.

> i want only my pages to access php files not from users

Only an HTTP client can request a URI. There is no way to distinguish between an HTTP client responding to an instruction from JavaScript that you have written from one that is responding to user input.

Comment: Well he could use url rewriting on the server-side, like in stackoverflow `/questions` is not a real folder in the server. I think that's what he meant?

Comment: What would be the point? Changing the URI wouldn't make them any less visible.

Comment: It hides one and creates another. So again, what is the point?

Comment: The another is not a php file path, so by that logic the php file path is hidden. The point for me would be beautiful urls while for the OP... ask him

Comment: @Esailija Re-read the OP, `so is there any way to stop user from viewing or opening php files from the url` The **URL**

Comment: Who cares about the "beauty" of a URI that is intended to only be accessed via JS anyway? People aren't the intended audience and nor are search engines.

Answer (score 1):

a possible way would be to obfuscate it so that its not user readible. expl; by using a main script and including the file by switching on some POST/GET param your sending (could be a random string, hash, number).
more efficient obfuscation can be acchieved, when you would redirect all traffic to one script via [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Somewhere in the url, you hide a number, that tells you which file to use. Then you add random string before and after it (with specific length) and read it from your main script. But then the user will find out by looking at the javascript.

but srsly. why do you care? there is no security by obscurity!

**/updated to your updated question;**
I think you want to be looking at your apache configuration; use [.htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html) or better, [disable indexing of a directory](http://www.felipecruz.com/blog_disable-directory-listing-browsing-apache.php) all together. The user wont be able to know about all your php files. Only the ones, you made public via links in your application. There is no such thing as "only letting ajax access file but not the user". because ajax IS the user and vice-verca! you are sending ajax request on behalf of the user! and if the user enters the url in the browserbar, its the same as sending an ajax request.
[You could add a special header with your ajax call](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method) (or use the one already supplied), but that wouldn't change anything, as soon as the user looks at the traffic close enought.
What I think you want is a [User Session](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to only allow privileged users to fully execute a script.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using jsp technology with apache tomcat, you can place your folders in the WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

No.

This is not possible. The client performs the request and the client is under the users control.